How to update Jump List for the Start Menu
There is a JumpList when you right click an app in the TaskBar.

There is another JumpList in the Start menu when you search.
The TaskBar JumpList  is always up to date.
The StartMenu JumpList is not up to date with applications shown.
Is there a way to manually refresh the StartMenu's JumpList without restarting?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-icustomdestinationlist


Right clicking in Windows brings up the Context Menu - its really hard to understand what you're asking: Right clicking the Start Menu and the Context Menu is not up to date - what does that mean, pictures might help? I'm tempted to upvote you based on your profile description. LOL

There are JumpList items in the Context Menu. But also when you search for an app in the start menu it also displays a JumpList. I did link the JumpList apis

@JeremyThompson https://superuser.com/questions/496059/what-is-a-jump-list-in-windows

Oh right, I've never heard of them. It'll be the explorer.exe process like you've found.

@JeremyThompson the JumpItems for firefox are Open new tab, Open new window, Enter private browsing

It seems that killing the "Windows Explorer" process does the trick

You could programmatically toggle off then back on the Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar setting in Windows to update the cache. The key is Start_TrackDocs in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
